# Merging or concat of multiple CSV files with a different number of columns and assigning a filename column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hi i am new to python pandas , and i am new doing code using dataframe . So i got a code from Internet on how to merge two or more csv file in a folder to one common csv file . but am not able get one line of code , i don't know how to do that . Can anyone help me in that please .

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

path = "/home/user/data/"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "data_*.csv"))
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
df_merged = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged.to_csv( "merged.csv")
```

so here i tried everything but am not able to get df_from_each_file . so can anyone help me in this
and i want the output to be like this

[So here is how my output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eke4V.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT #2: The actual data was different than the sample data and needed to be concatted horizontally rather than vertically by passing `axis=1`. This creates duplicate columns so the dataframe needs to be transposed with `.T` in order to drop these duplicate columns as duplicate rows with `drop_duplicates()`. Finally, it needs to be transposed back once again with `.T`. Also, we had to exclude hearers when reading in the files as two of the files had the exact same value, so they would have inadvertently been dropped. That's why we had to read in the column headers as values and then promote them back to headers at the end and drop the first row with `.iloc`.

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in all_files], axis=1).T.drop_duplicates().T.to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]
df.to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT #1: As discussed on LinkedIn, all of your data was in one column, so in order to read it in as multiple columns, you need to use `sep='\s+'`, because there are multiple spaces separating your data, so you can use `\s+` as a separator or delimiter.

For a one-liner, use `.assign` with `file=os.path.basename(f)`

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+').assign(file=os.path.basename(f)) for f in all_files]).to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

Per your comment, I tested this exact code with different columns and had a successful result:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os
path = 'Desktop'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "Book*.csv"))
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+').assign(file=os.path.basename(f)) for f in all_files]).to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

If the excel files are already separated into columns, then remove `sep='\s+'` and use this code:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(file=os.path.basename(f)) for f in all_files]).to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

Book1.csv

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       2       3       4       5
```

Book2.csv

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
2       3       4       5
```

merged.csv

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    file
1       2       3       4       5       Book1.csv
2       3       4       5               Book2.csv
```

Comment: its giving me a different output , not as the one i mentioned in question , i want all headers to  be together , following data of that . For example if in my first csv file i have 3 coloumns =>col1,col2,col3 , in second csv file i have headers => col1,col2,col4 and the third one with 4 headers => col1,col2,col5,col6 .   So i want my output headers to be => col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6 ... combining all the three file headers

Comment: what is different about the output @dhanyabalakrishnan ? This should work as I use it all of the time.

Comment: if so can you paste entire code so that i can check with mine

Comment: @dhanyabalakrishnan see my revised answer.

Comment: its giving me an output like this ,

Comment: col1    col2    col3    col4    col5,file,col1    col2    col3    col4   
1       2       3       4       5,test1.csv,
,test2.csv,2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4       5,test3.csv,

Comment: Are you sure the column headers are the same? Are you able to share two sample files with different columns? Can you share with github?

Comment: may i know you username or email ?